# Get the file path from portable device in windows

Tags: php, windows-explorer

I wrote a php script to copy files from an iPhone connected by USB.

The issue is that I need a path for the scandir function and because the iPhone is seen as a portable device the path I get from the explorer is something like "This computer\Apple iphone\Internal storage\DCIM" and I would need something like "C:/something/"

How can I get the portable device path to reach the iphone content ?

Comment: The iPhone is not mounted as a normal device, so you can't access it like the file system directly. I would guess it's likely mounted as an MTP device. If that's true you'd need to work with that API, normal filesystem functions won't work. Check out https://superuser.com/questions/369959/how-do-i-access-mtp-devices-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

You would need to work with [Windows Portable Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windows-portable-devices)  API.

iPhone in Windows is not mounted as a part of the filesystem, so it can not be accessed by normal php filesystem functions.

Microsoft provides documentation here for C++: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/programming-guide

It should be possible to access these functions from PHP using FFI: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ffi.php but this is far from a trivial task, as you'd need to create bindings for the C++ library.